# Erro na ordenação de números

Tags: c, algoritmo, classificação

Os números pares eu consegui ordenar, só que os números impares não consigo ordenar. Aparece o endereço de memória do número.

Link para a questão: [Pares e Ímpares](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1259)

Eis o meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int teste, i, j, aux, aux1, c1 = 0, c2 = 0;
    scanf("%d", &teste);
    int vetor[teste], par[teste], impar[teste];
    for(i = 0; i < teste; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < teste; i++)
    {
        if(vetor[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            par[i] = vetor[i];
            c1++;
        }
        else
        {
            impar[i] = vetor[i];
            c2++;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < teste - 1; i++)
    {
        for(j = i + 1; j < teste; j++)
        {
            if(par[i] > par[j])
            {
                aux = par[i];
                par[i] = par[j];
                par[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<teste-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<teste;j++)
        {
            if(impar[i]<impar[j])
            {
                aux1=impar[i];
                impar[i]=impar[j];
                impar[j]=aux1;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<c1;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",par[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<c2;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",impar[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que a ordem saia errada por não considerar todos os itens.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int quantidade;
    scanf("%d", &quantidade);
    int par[quantidade], impar[quantidade], qtdePar = 0, qtdeImpar = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < quantidade; i++)  {
        int entrada;
        scanf("%d", &entrada);
        if (entrada % 2 == 0) par[qtdePar++] = entrada;
        else impar[qtdeImpar++] = entrada;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < qtdePar; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < qtdePar; j++) {
            if (par[i] > par[j]) {
                int aux = par[i];
                par[i] = par[j];
                par[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < qtdeImpar; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < qtdeImpar; j++) {
            if (impar[i] < impar[j]) {
                int aux = impar[i];
                impar[i] = impar[j];
                impar[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < qtdePar; i++) printf("%d\n", par[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < qtdeImpar; i++) printf("%d\n", impar[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/wX2GOB). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pdrqlhgl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/SortEvenOdd.c).

Comment: Gostaria de entender o que está errado na resposta.

Comment: Eu estava errando na hora da quantidade dos pares e ímpares,obrigado pela ajuda